# Puthon OPCUA Client - get many tags from topic

Tags: python-asyncio, opc-ua

I try to get over 19000 number of tags from OPCUA by path "ns=2;s=TEST.PLC1"
In "Tags_List" i write dictionary "Tagname:adress_of_tag" like "TEST1:"ns=2;s=TEST1".
Next i create list "tasks" and write to him commands to get value from tags.
Next i execute all task in tasks "await asyncio.gather(*tasks)" and write result to "RESULT" - do all tasks at the same time.
Time create "Tags_List" = 0.5sec
Time create "tasks" = 3.5 sec.
What i do wrong?
 How i can minimalize time create "tasks"?
Finaly i want get 50000 value of tags less then 1 sek.
Thnx.

```
import asyncio
import sys
import aiopg
from asyncua import Client as ClientASY
import datetime
#asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(asyncio.WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy())
#asyncio.Semaphore(value=9999)
```

url = "opc.tcp://127.0.0.1:49320"

```
async def create_tags_dict(path, client):
    tag_list = dict()
    node = client.get_node(path)
    variables = await node.get_variables()
    for i in variables:
        tag_list[i.nodeid.Identifier] = i
    return tag_list
```

```
async def get_value_from_dict(address, client):
    value = await client.get_node(address).get_value()
    return value
```

```
async def main():
    node_path = "ns=2;s=TEST.PLC1"
    async with ClientASY(url=url) as clientAsy:
        Tags_List = await create_tags_dict(node_path, clientAsy)
        await asyncio.sleep(2)

        tasks = []
        for key, value in Tags_List.items():
            tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(get_value_from_dict(value, clientAsy)))
        RESULT = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

        await asyncio.sleep(1)
```

if **name** == "**main**":
asyncio.run(main())

Answer (score 0):

Each call to get_value, is creating a network call.
You can use read_values from client to read all values in one network request.

```
nodes = list(Tags_List.values())
values = await clientAsy.read_values(nodes)
```

Comment: result the same

Comment: Then the server is just slow, nothing you can do about, maybe try use multiple clients.